# Property buckets in Python

Tags: python, dynamic

Ok, serious noob question here, so I'm looking for a very general answer. I'm new to Python, and the language seems straightforward enough, but I'm having a problem when I approach a problem. Coming from static typed languages, my first instinct is to make some objects so I can pass buckets of relevant data around while keeping my logic terse and simple.

But is this a thing in Python? Since the language is dynamically typed, is there any point in making an object to pass around? Why would I define fields in advance if I can just set them on the fly? And if I don't have fields, why would I bother with an object at all? Couldn't I use a dictionary and it's basically the same?

So I guess I'm asking, if I need to separate my data access code from my logic, is a property bucket a good idea? Or do people not do this in Python and just use dictionaries?

EDIT:

Here's a basic idea of what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have an http api that returns a json string. I want to hit that url with urllib2, bring it back as a string, and use json.loads to turn it into a dict object. Then I want to separate the mysql code into another class. Obviously I don't want to pass 20 values around, and since I already have a dict with all my values, what would be the benefit to creating a dynamic object and adding each value from the dict? I'm still going to have to know all the names in the data access class right? I'm not really talking about performance, but more about design.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing your concrete requirements, I'd say that dictionaries are *probably* better, if you want to pass around data. They are built-in, it's fast, simple and every programmer understands them, in contrast to something like value objects, where the developer will have to look up the specific attributes.

Examples:

- at [WSGI](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (Web Server Gateway Interface) core is an [environments dictionary](http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_environment_dictionary)
- [Werkzeug's MultiDict](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/datastructures.py#L275) is used to hold request arguments
- [flask's config](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L273) is just a dict
- ...

Also relevant in this context: Jack Diederich's [Stop writing classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0) (YT):

> Classes are great but they are also overused. This talk will describe examples of class overuse taken from real world code and refactor the unnecessary classes, exceptions, and modules out of them.

Answer (score 2):

For read-only data, [named tuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is a good choice, you can access value by field name and it's more memory-efficient than a dictionary. In my opinion, data that get passed around should be made read-only.

Edit: For your use case, I think you should just pass the dictionary down the pipelines. Creating a class just for data storage and provide no other service just further complicate the code with little benefit.

Comment: Wow! I had never seen that before - that's *really* handy!

Comment: ok, that's the conclusion I'm coming to, just dictionaries. I have to ask, doesn't this make separating code into different modules harder to use? How would someone else use this code without digging into it at runtime to see what's in the dictionary?

Comment: The API (i.e dictionary key) should be documented and and the user should use them according to document. Even if you class how can the use know the interface of the class if not for documents :)

Answer (score 0):

You actually find a lot of both. If the code is "strictly Python" folks tend not to make POPO-type or DTO-type objects. Folks tend to just pass about the data they need. However, if you're communicating with other services, the communication plumbing may make heavier-type objects that you have to deal with (Suds, for instance, does a pretty close mapping of the data types in the service to Python objects).

Fortunately (or not), you can kinda' have the best of both worlds. You may see a "generic DTO" something like the following (not necessarily *good*, but pythonic):

```
   class Person:
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.__dict__ = kwargs
```

So while there are no `surname` or `givenName` type properties set on them, you can add them just for the syntactic sugar of it. (Useful if you're doing a list comprehension):

```
last_names = [x.surname for x in people]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a dictionary unless I wanted a generic key-value data type because I didn't know what the keys would be. For all the cases you'd use an object in C++ or similar, you can, and should probably, use an object in Python.

The reason is that although you could use a `dict`, it doesn't offer encapsulation or abstraction. Even coming from statically typed languages, you should understand the benefits of this. You can't make a `dict` validate its values. There's no convenient place to document the structure of a `dict`, or to name that structure.

Interestingly, the attributes of a Python object *are* a dictionary. Check this out:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.cat = 'meow'
...     self.dot = 'woof'
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.__dict__
{'dot': 'woof', 'cat': 'meow'}
```

And, you can make a class look like a `dict`:

```
>>> class Animals(object):
...   def __getitem__(self, key):
...     if key == 'cat':
...       return 'meow'
...     if key == 'dog':
...       return 'woof'
...     raise KeyError(key)
... 
>>> a = Animals()
>>> a['cat']
'meow'
>>> a['dog']
'woof'
```

Comment: Actually, there are some nice data validation frameworks for python, e.g. https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous.

Comment: In your second example why don't you just return `self.__dict__[key]`?

Comment: @tcaswell suppose I could. It was just meant to demonstrate that a class can act like a dict. A less contrived example could have more complex code in there. Maybe it queries a database, or something.

Comment: fair enough.  I think you should mention that this gives you a nice upgrade path if you start with dictionaries (because they are simple to code up), you can always switch to a `class` later and not have to change any of your client code.